# How to print through BT using WinCE?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I need to print to O'Neil printer through BT using WinCE

how I can do it ?

thank's in advance

Comment: ok, i've reader, it's bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

About the bluetooth I use 32Feet solution for WinCe: http://inthehand.com/content/32feet.aspx

About the format there are sample files at:
http://www.oneilprinters.com/support_software.php?pageHeader=support&subHeader=software

Comment: Your suggested site states the solution is for PPC. Have you tried it on Windows CE?

Comment: For the 32Feet I am sure, because I use it in my application which works on a WinCE 5.0 application.

Regarding the site about "oneil printers" I putted it as a reference, never used that printer.